# Efficient way to Sort CSV raw string data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a raw csv data as mentioned below

```
  James,Mary,Patricia,Anthony,Donald\n
  145,10,100,39,101\n
  21,212,313,28,1
```

In above mentioned string, columns are comma `,` separated, first line is `column` and after each `\n` a new row where the data is for each person. What I am trying to achieve here is it should be sorted as mentioned below.

```
  Anthony,Donald,James,Mary,Patricia\n
  39,101, 145,10,100\n
  28,1,21,212,313
```

**What I have tried so  far is**, splitting based on `\n`, further splitting based on comma `,` for each value, but in this case there will be no proper reference to sort value.

What Part I am Struggling with

```
        string data = "James,Mary,Patricia,Anthony,Donald\n145,10,100,39,101\n21,212,313,28,1";

        var rows = data.Split('\n');
        var unorderedNames = rows[0].Split(',');
```

Split Array based on \n

[image]

Split Names based on `,` comma -

[image]

Now, If I implement sorting, I believe I will loose all references because names will be sorted but below in row 2 and 3, mentioned payments will not.

In my code mentioned above, The first line split the array into three based on \n. Then when I soft first line, I beleive I don't have reference of other values in the same array.

I appreciate if you can assist me to find some efficient method to convert this raw data into sored alphabetically with values in efficient way.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are asking. It sounds like you want to “read” the data from a CSV file AND at the same time… “sort” the data? It will be a challenge and wasted effort IMO to sort the data while reading it. Simply “read” the data into some collection… THEN sort the collection. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Where's your sample code?

Comment: @JohnV I have shared my implementation. I believe I will loose the sequence of payments if I sort the column names.

Comment: @JohnG I appreciate your suggestion. What I am trying to achieve is read csv, and pass its RAW string to another function to sort. I know we can do using File Reader and some LINQ but I am looking for some help if we sort raw string then what would be the best and efficient solution. Thanks

Comment: @JohnG consider it as you are getting a raw csv data from api which you need to to SORT that raw data. I hope it make sense.

Comment: I am not following “how” you want to sort the data. In your example the data is “sorted” solely by the first row of data. In reference to your comment… _”I know we can do using File Reader and some LINQ… “_ … ? … Can you show an example of this as I do not agree that this can be done. Any effort to “sort” the data “while” reading it is only going to be LESS efficient than simply reading the data THEN sorting it.

Comment: @JohnG If you are not able to understand then better to leave for others to look into it. I think I have clearly mentioned the data examples How it is in raw form and how it will look like after the sort.. read again if you want to help.

Comment: @JohnG if you want to explore what I am requesting for, here you go `https://greywyvern.com/?post=258`

Comment: I think i get the problem. You want to sort the columns of a CSV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StackDemo
    {
        private string source = "James,Mary,Patricia,Anthony,Donald\n145,10,100,39,101\n21,212,313,28,1";

        public string ProcessString()
        {

            var rows = source.Split('\n');

            var row1Values = rows[0].Split(',');
            var row2Values = rows[1].Split(',');
            var row3Values = rows[2].Split(',');

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
            {
                people.Add(new Person()
                {
                    Name = row1Values[index],
                    SomeValue = row2Values[index],
                    OtherValue = row3Values[index]
                });
            }

            people.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));

            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            List<string> someValues = new List<string>();
            List<string> otherValues = new List<string>();

            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                names.Add(p.Name);
                someValues.Add(p.SomeValue);
                otherValues.Add(p.OtherValue);
            }


            string result = "";
            result = BuildString(names, result);
            result = BuildString(someValues, result);
            result = BuildString(otherValues, result);

            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);

            return result;
        }

        private static string BuildString(List<string> names, string result)
        {
            foreach (string s in names)
            {
                result += s + ",";
            }

            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
            result += "\n";
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }
        public string OtherValue { get; set; }
    }
```

This code is extremely basic, (rude) but it does what I think you want?)

Also it returns the string in the same format as it was received.

EDIT: Expanded on comment question!

Added some unit tests to help validate how I understood your question:

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestWith5()
        {
            string input = "James,Mary,Patricia,Anthony,Donald\n145,10,100,39,101\n21,212,313,28,1";
            string expected = "Anthony,Donald,James,Mary,Patricia\n39,101,145,10,100\n28,1,21,212,313";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestWith4()
        {
            string input = "James,Mary,Patricia,Anthony,\n145,10,100,39,\n21,212,313,28,";
            string expected = ",Anthony,James,Mary,Patricia\n,39,145,10,100\n,28,21,212,313";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestWith3()
        {
            string input = "James,Mary,Patricia,,\n145,10,100,,\n21,212,313,,";
            string expected = ",,James,Mary,Patricia\n,,145,10,100\n,,21,212,313";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestWith2()
        {
            string input = ",,James,Mary,\n,,145,10,\n,,21,212,";
            string expected = ",,,James,Mary\n,,,145,10\n,,,21,212";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestWith1()
        {
            string input = "James,,,,\n145,,,,\n21,,,,";
            string expected = "James,,,,\n145,,,,\n21,,,,";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestWith0()
        {
            string input = ",,,,\n,,,,\n,,,,";
            string expected = ",,,,\n,,,,\n,,,,";

            // arrange
            StackDemo3 subject = new StackDemo3();

            // act
            string actualResult = subject.ProcessString(input);

            // assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actualResult);
        }
    }
```

Here is the actual implementation:

```
public interface IStringPeopleParser
{
    List<Person> ConvertToPeople(string input);
}

public interface IPeopleStringParser
{
    string ConvertPeopleToString(List<Person> people);
}

public class PeopleStringParser : IPeopleStringParser
    {
        public string ConvertPeopleToString(List<Person> people)
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            List<string> someValues = new List<string>();
            List<string> otherValues = new List<string>();

            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                names.Add(p.Name);
                someValues.Add(p.SomeValue);
                otherValues.Add(p.OtherValue);
            }

            string output = "";
            output += string.Join(",", names);
            output += "\n";
            output += string.Join(",", someValues);
            output += "\n";
            output += string.Join(",", otherValues);

            return output;
        }
    }

public class StringPeopleParser : IStringPeopleParser
    {
        public List<Person> ConvertToPeople(string source)
        {
            var rows = source.Split('\n');

            string[] row1Values = rows[0].Split(',');
            string[] row2Values = rows[1].Split(',');
            string[] row3Values = rows[2].Split(',');

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            for (int index = 0; index < row1Values.Length; index++)
            {
                people.Add(new Person()
                {
                    Name = row1Values[index],
                    SomeValue = row2Values[index],
                    OtherValue = row3Values[index]
                });
            }

            return people;
        }
    }

public class StackDemo3
    {
        IStringPeopleParser stringPeopleParser = new StringPeopleParser();
        IPeopleStringParser peopleStringParser = new PeopleStringParser();

        public string ProcessString(string s) {
            List<Person> people = stringPeopleParser.ConvertToPeople(s);
            int validCount = people.Where(x => x.IsValid()).Count();
            switch (validCount)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    {
                        return peopleStringParser.ConvertPeopleToString(people);
                    }
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    {
                        people = people.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
                        return peopleStringParser.ConvertPeopleToString(people);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        return "";//outside bounds of reality. Should never happen.
                    }
            }
        }

    }

public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }
        public string OtherValue { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid() {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SomeValue) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OtherValue))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Also I don't really know why you don't want the person class?
You need to have a reference between the 3 values possible in each row (the index value is the key) by creating the Person class, the class instance becomes said reference.

Comment: Thanks @Morten. What if there are only two column or one column in the data?

Comment: Well that depends? if there is only 1 column, then it is simple. There is only one set of properies to sort by, so. That is just sort array?

Two columns, is one less property, so you just don't load in the value, or create a new object that only has two columns.

But if you mean, what if array "names" has 5 values, and the other two have different values, then the entire thing collapses, how do you know which values belong together if the columns don't match?

Or do you mean if there are less items overall in the data set?

Comment: in CSV if data is empty then there will always a comma i.e. `32,,21,,1`.  So what actually it will be doing is, `1.` if data is already sorted, it will not sort. `2.` it will also handle single column if there is any and will not sort. `3.` if there are two columns it will sort . `4. ` The max data it can have is 5 columns.

Comment: I believe instead of using Person class, can we implement StringBuilder so that it can manage columns length and data?

Comment: I have added an edit to the original answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Forgot to add the person class. hehe.. .whoops.

Comment: Please have a look at this `https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/`

Comment: I am not sure what you want me to see here? 
This is merely a library that enables a series of behaviours for you, your question is specifically about your own code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you want to sort the headers of your CSV into some "whatever" order, and have the data "go with it"

Come up with some way to represent your data as a 2D array:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");

var data = lines.Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToArray(); //nasty way of parsing a CSV but it's accessory to this discussion..

var head = lines[0]
             .Split(',')
             .Select((s,i) => new { Name = s, Index = i })
             .OrderBy(at => at.Name)
             .ToArray();
```

`head` is now the sorted headers, but it has an additional property that tells you what column in `data` holds that person's data. Anthony is first in `heaD`, but their Index is 3 so we should get Anthony's data from `data[3]`

```
foreach(var person in head){
  Console.WriteLine($"Now printing {person.name} data from column {person.Index}");

  foreach(var line in data){
    Console.Writeline(line[person.Index]);
  }

}
```

We didn't bother sorting the data (it's more efficient not to), we just stored what column it's in as part of the object that does get sorted, and then regardless of person sort order, we access the data via that column. Sorting `head` is very fast, because it's just a few names. It always maintains its map of "where is the data" because `Index` doesn't change regardless of the sort order of `head`

Comment: Thanks @Cauise. This is not sorting header. Also, I am getting string from API;  not File

Comment: The header is sorted by `OrderBy(at => at.Name)` It doesn't really matter where the data comes from- File.ReadAllLines reads a file and split on \n. If you already have the data in a string from an API, Split it on \n to get the to same position you would as if you had done a File.ReadAllLines